# Find IP/Name of client connected to WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, was

**Hi,**

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS7 that uses WAS to communicate over TCP. At the service side I have implemented the IParameterInspector to log service operations that is called but I also need the client IP/Name.

I have tried this :

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name].Address
```

But that will always return "::1" ? If I use :

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(messageProperty.Address).HostName.Split('.').LastOrDefault()
```

The name will always be local and this is even when the client is on a diffrent computer then the service?

**BestRegards**

Edit 1: The IP is not possible to get if I have read right so then the question is if there is any other way to specifie a client, maby some kind of GUID or is it only session ID I should use?

Comment: You appear to have written code made to get the *local* address via a convoluted way.

Comment: Yes it seems so, the question is how I get the client IP? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may receive an [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address (as you have here).  `::1` is the IPv6 equivalent to `127.0.0.1` on IPv4.

In addition, not all IP addresses have a host name associated with them, and some may not have any periods (eg if you get 'localhost' or another local LAN machine name)

Comment: I could probably live with only the IP(IPV4) adress of the client but Im sure that the remote client is not located on my local computer where I have the service. So how do I find out the client IP/Domain Name in the IParameterInspector?